# Getting a different MD5 check sum for the same file which is saved in different folder

Tags: android, md5sum

I'm trying to download .apk files from the  android  emulator and  calculate it's md5 check sum.I made an interesting observation here!!

Everytime i download a .apk file into the same folder the md5 check sum value remains the same.

When I download the same  .apk file to a different folder the md5 check sum value changes.

Can I conclude by saying that md5 check sum of a file depends on the location of  where the  file is stored??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `MD5 checkSum` of a file depends on the `location` where you `saved it`.

Comment: By any chance,can we have something like md5 ..that remains constant irrespective of the location saved